# Multiple hostnames for a single Wordpress blog to control displayed post categories

Tags: php, wordpress

**Wordpress related**

Multiple hostnames for a single Wordpress blog to control displayed post categories

Can it be done?
If not, why not
Else, how may I? :3

I'm trying to maintain a single blog but only show posts from a particular category for a certain host name :/

I found http://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop#Exclude_Posts_From_Some_Category but it's not going to change the domain in links, etc :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thomas - there are a few ways you could achieve this.  If you want a solution that doesn't involve setting up a separate WP network for each hostname (assuming you're using WP 3.1), a neat way might be to rewrite the URL at the web server.  WP already requires you to cofigure rewrite rules for pretty URL support, so there's no reason why you could internally map `category.example.com` into `www.example.com/category`.  If you made all your site's links relative, this could work reasonably well.

Otherwise, I'd create a network for each hostname, and write a multi-site plugin that adjusts the WP_Query for any request received on a 'category' network, to retrieve posts from the main blog with a category filter.  But you'd probably end up fighting WP every step of the way :-)

There may be a neater solution.